# Javascript - Usar coma como separador de miles

Tags: javascript, vue.js

He visto demasiados ejemplos, pero ninguno me ha convencido a lo que realmente quiero y la mejor práctica para realizar esto.

Tengo mi código de la siguiente manera:

```
const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat("es-MX");
let anualidad = 1200;
this.model.enero = nf.format(anualidad);

output: 1200
```

Mi problema es que no coloca la coma en `1,200`; no digo que no funcione, porque si coloco otro cero me agrega la coma de esta manera `12,000`.

Ya configure el idioma a **MX**.

¿Como puedo realizar esto de la mejor manera? ya que son demasiados cálculos los que deben hacerse de esta manera.

Comment: te recomiendo usar numeralJS, lo puedes encontrar aca en http://numeraljs.com/ facilita todo con el formato de numeros

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hice una investigación bastante exhaustiva del tema, y basaré mi respuesta sobre el resultado obtenido en la misma.

En primer lugar, aunque ya se ha discutido la posibilidad de usar otro sistema de `locale` (por ejemplo `en-US`), eso no responde totalmente la pregunta.

Claramente deseas realizar la conversión de un tipo [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number) a un tipo [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String), pero que el mismo represente una cifra con formato local para `es-MX` (español de México).

Si hacemos uso del método [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString), o del método [`NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat) del objeto [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Intl), obtenemos como resultado lo siguiente:

```js
const number = 1200;
const number2 = 12000;
console.log(number.toLocaleString('es-MX')); // 1200
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX').format(number)); // 1200
console.log(number2.toLocaleString('es-MX')); // 12,000
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX').format(number2)); // 12,000
```

Claramente no coloca la coma decimal si la cantidad de dígitos para el grupo de miles es menor que 2.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una forma de resolver este problema (digo problema, aunque no es un `bug` del lenguaje, sino una decisión de estandarización) es realizar manualmente la conversión del número, ya que el estándar no nos está aportando el resultado deseado.

En tu pregunta indicas que has visto muchas formas, pero ninguna te convence. La verdad es que *para gustos, los colores*.

Esta es mi propuesta, pero entiendo que puede hacerse de muchas otras formas.

Creamos nuestra propia función de formato, apoyados en la máquina de [Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp) del motor de JavaScript.

Usaremos la siguiente expresión regular para dar formato a nuestro número en el lenguaje local deseado:

```
const miRegEx = /(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
```

En esta expresión regular se hace un `positive lookahead` (`?=`), buscando uno o varios (`+`) grupos de 3 dígitos (`(\d{3})+`), si los hay devuelve `match` junto con los valores agrupados en 3. Luego, se realiza un `negative lookahead` (`(?!)`) para descartar cualquier dígito que no sea agrupado por el primer grupo de captura (en este caso 1 o 2 dígitos). Puedes leer más sobre `lookahead` en [Regex Lookahead](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php).

Usaremos el método [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) del objeto [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String), el cual acepta una expresión regular (la cual ya tenemos) y un [parámetro de tipo `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace#Especificando_una_cadena_como_un_par.C3.A1metro) con el siguiente formato:

> `$n` ó `$nn` Donde n o nn son dígitos decimales positivos menores a 100, inserta la subcadena emparejada de orden n del paréntesis, proporcionado por el primer argumento del objeto RegExp.

Así, nuestro parámetro será el siguiente:

```
$1,
```

Donde `$1` representa el primer argumento: nuestra expresión regular, y `,` es el símbolo de separación de miles que usaremos para este caso.

Por último, debemos tomar la decisión de si utilizamos siempre este método para sustituir el método `toLocaleString()` o podemos combinar ambos.

Supongamos que vamos a usar siempre este método para cualquier valor numérico válido:

```js
const numero = 123.456789;
const numero2 = 1234.56789;
const numero3 = 123456.789;
const numero4 = 1234567.89;

const formatoMexico = (number) => {
  const exp = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
  const rep = '$1,';
  return number.toString().replace(exp,rep);
}

console.log(formatoMexico(numero));  // 123.456,789  <= NO VALIDO
console.log(formatoMexico(numero2)); // 1,234.56,789 <= NO VALIDO
console.log(formatoMexico(numero3)); // 123,456.789
console.log(formatoMexico(numero4)); // 1,234,567.89
```

Claramente tenemos un grave problema, ya que hay resultados no válidos.

El problema está en que el reemplazo se realiza sin tomar en cuenta que las posiciones decimales no deberían ser parte del reemplazo.

Para solucionar este problema tenemos algunas opciones, y como dije anteriormente: *para gustos, los colores*.

Como un número en Javascript sólo puede contener un carácter `.` o ninguno, usaremos esto para aplicar nuestra función sólo sobre la parte entera del número.

Vamos a separar la parte entera de la parte decimal, aplicamos el formato a la parte entera y luego concatenaremos nuevamente todo en un `String`.

```js
const numero = 123;
const numero2 = 1234;
const numero3 = 123.456789;
const numero4 = 1234.56789;
const numero5 = 123456.789;
const numero6 = 1234567.89;

const formatoMexico = (number) => {
  const exp = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
  const rep = '$1,';
  let arr = number.toString().split('.');
  arr[0] = arr[0].replace(exp,rep);
  return arr[1] ? arr.join('.'): arr[0];
}

console.log(formatoMexico(numero));  // 123
console.log(formatoMexico(numero2)); // 1,234
console.log(formatoMexico(numero3)); // 123.456789
console.log(formatoMexico(numero4)); // 1,234.56789
console.log(formatoMexico(numero5)); // 123,456.789
console.log(formatoMexico(numero6)); // 1,234,567.89
```

Con esto tenemos una función que nos ayuda a convertir números a su representación de cadena en formato local de México (punto decimal y comas para separación de miles).

Aplicando esto a tu código, podrías tener:

```js
const formatoMexico = (number) => {
  const exp = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
  const rep = '$1,';
  let arr = number.toString().split('.');
  arr[0] = arr[0].replace(exp,rep);
  return arr[1] ? arr.join('.'): arr[0];
}

let anualidad = 1200;
this.model.enero = formatoMexico(anualidad);

// output: 1,200
```

Modificando un poco este método podemos hacerlo para cualquier sistema de representación numérica que deseemos.

**¿Porqué `toLocaleString()` o `FormatNumber()` no colocan el símbolo de miles para cifras entre 1000 y 9999?**

Es una decisión tomada (no sé el motivo) por la organización de estandarización de [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/basic-info/overview/). En particular por el proyecto [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (siglas de ***C**ommon **L**ocale **D**ata **R**repository*).

En el [estándar](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35.html) se establece entre otras cosas, el patron de [formato numérico](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns). Y dentro de ese patrón, existe una propiedad o atributo llamado [**`minimumGroupingDigits`**](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Examples_of_minimumGroupingDigits), la cual establece la cantidad de dígitos mínimos de un grupo para usar el separador de miles.

El hecho es que este valor es igual a 2 (como puede verse en [CLDR Survey Tool](https://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/es_MX/Symbols/70ef5e0c9d323e01)) en todos los formatos numéricos pertenecientes a la especificación `es` (que incluye a México).

Debido a esto, los métodos antes mencionados, siempre devolverán enteros de 4 cifras sin separador de miles.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Con argentina tampoco funciona es-AR

Usando el formato alemán, da el resultado requerido:

```
Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE").format()
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de las etiquetas IETF el código para América Latina y Caribe es `es-419` y tiene bastante sentido puesto que en Argentina, Colombia o México la expresión es la misma.

> Language-Region:
>
> de-DE (German for Germany)
>
> en-US (English as used in the United States)
>
> es-419 (Spanish appropriate for the Latin America and Caribbean
> region using the UN region code)

Puedes consultarlo [aquí](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646)

Estuve haciendo unas pruebas pero desafortunadamente esa etiqueta no está funcionando. Lo que si es que, si no le pasas nada al constructor este toma el formato que estas buscando.

```js
const anualidad = 1200;

const nf  = new Intl.NumberFormat().format( anualidad );
const nf2 = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-419').format( anualidad );
const nf3 = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX').format( anualidad );


console.log( nf, nf2, nf3 );
```

Espero te puedas guiar

**EDIT**

Haciendo unas pruebas utilicé un rastreador del Objeto `Intl.NumberFormat()` y encontré que el `Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions()` Tiene un objeto de este tipo

```
{
locale: "en-US"
maximumFractionDigits: 3
minimumFractionDigits: 0
minimumIntegerDigits: 1
notation: "standard"
numberingSystem: "latn"
signDisplay: "auto"
style: "decimal"
useGrouping: true
}
```

Esto puede cambiar dependiendo el navegador que se esté utilizando.
Le he pasado al constructor el tag `en-MX` por que en algunas ocasiones funciona (Lo he visto en otros proyectos) o Voilá! funcionó.

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta, hacer lo siguiente: `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX').format(12000));` producirá: `12,000` mientras que hacer esto otro: `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-VE').format(12000));` producirá: `12.000`. Por lo tanto, si que existe `es-MX`. Recuerda que no todos los países de América Latina y el Caribe usan el Sistema Internacional, como México, por ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: Que raro, por que en el snippet que hice no funciona, pero hice la sentencia completa en una consola de Chrome  y funcionó.

Comment: El tema de la pregunta, es que funciona para números de 5 dígitos o más, pero no para números de 4 dígitos. Esto va con cualquiera de las etiquetas `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-419').format(10000)); //10,000`, pero esto no `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-419').format(9999)); // 9999` (no le agrega la coma)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number = 123456.789;

alert(new Intl.NumberFormat("es-MX", {style: "currency", currency: "MXN"}).format(number));
```

**Te recomiendo lo siguiente:**

```
var number = 123456.789;
alert(new Intl.NumberFormat("es-MX", {style: "currency", currency: "MXN"}).format(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adaptacion del codigo de Mauricio Contreras para España (es-ES) (por ejemplo 1.234,56):

```
const formatoMexico = (number) => {
    const exp = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
    const rep = '$1.';
    let arr = number.toString().split('.');
    arr[0] = arr[0].replace(exp,rep);
    return arr[1] ? arr.join(','): arr[0];
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Creo que es mucho mas sencilla, debe tener mejor performance esta aproximación y me dio mejores resultados, sobre todo cuando se le pasa dinámicamente el valor desde un input, toma como parámetro un Numero o String y devuelve un string agregando las comas necesarias.

```
function commaToK (price) {
  if (!isNaN(price)) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
      maximumSignificantDigits: 4,
    }).format(price);
  } else {
    let newpriceString = price.replace(/,/g, "");
    let newPrice = parseFloat(newpriceString);
       return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
      maximumSignificantDigits: 4,
    }).format(newPrice);
  }
};

console.log(commaToK(12000))   // Devuelve "12,000"
console.log(commaToK("1200000"))  // Devuelve "1,200,00"
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).