# Remplazar punto por coma en decimal con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Necesito que despues de los decimales aparezca una coma y no un punto
lo estoy intentando de esta manera pero no lo he logrado

```js
 var  currentmonth = '1.211.25';
    var currentmonth = currentmonth.toString();
    var currentmonth = currentmonth.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
console.log(currentmonth)
```

ejemplo de como quiero que devuelva el resultado :
1.211,25

Comment: Relacionado: [Javascript - usar coma como separador de miles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/312677/javascript-usar-coma-como-separador-de-miles/312786#312786)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomando tu código de inicio quedaría algo así para el número de ejemplo que pusiste:

```js
var  currentmonth = '1.211.25';
    var currentmonth = currentmonth.toString();
    var currentmonth = currentmonth.replace(/\.(\d{2})$/g, ",$1");
console.log(currentmonth)
```

**EDIT:** Suponiendo que la variable es un número del formato 123456.78 se aplica formato de coma decimal y punto de miles.

```js
this.hourlast = +this.extra[i].horas;
this.hourlast = this.hourlast.toLocaleString('es');
```

Comment: Al momento de implementarlo en mi codigo me devuelve : 1211,25 los millares no aparecen, como podria solucionar esto?

Comment: cuál es el verdadero input de tu código, no creo que sea `1.211.25`

Comment: this.hourlast = this.extra[i].horas;
            this.hourlast = this.hourlast.toString();
            this.hourlast = this.hourlast.replace(/\.(\d{2})$/g, ",$1");

Comment: supongo que tu variable `this.extra[i].horas` devuelve el número `1211.25`, prueba con el código que edité

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera me funciono correctamente :

```
this.hourlast = +this.extra[i].horas;
this.hourlast = this.hourlast.toLocaleString('de-DE');
```