# ¿Cómo establecer formato de moneda con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Este código funciona, pero pone el signó delante de la cantidad  ($1,345.99) y necesito por favor que aparezca al final  (1,345.99 $)

**JavaScript**

```
var formato = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'MXN',
});

function GetDetalle() {
    var id = $('#MovId').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlGetDetalle,
        data: { id: id },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $('#tableDetalle tbody tr').remove();
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    let tr = `<tr>
                      <td> ${item.Articulo} </td>
                      <td> ${item.Descripcion} </td>
                      <td> ${item.Cantidad} </td>
                      <td> ${formato.format(item.Costo)} </td>
                      <td> ${formato.format(item.Impuestos)} </td>
                      <td> ${formato.format(item.Total)} </td>
                      </tr>`;
                    $('#tableDetalle tbody').append(tr);
                });

            } else {
                $('#tableDetalle tbody tr').remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Saludos. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/312677/javascript-usar-coma-como-separador-de-miles/312786

Comment: ¿Agregar el símbolo al final manualmente seria un problema?

Comment: No tendria problema en agregarlo Hardcode  al final...me interesa mas utilizar la coma como separador de miles el punto para los decimales y mostrar 2 digitos de la parte decimal ...ejemplo:  1,345.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes permitirte añadir el símbolo posteriormente en el html:

```
const formato = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX', { maximumFractionDigits: 2 });

....

<td> ${formato.format(item.Costo)} $ </td>
<td> ${formato.format(item.Impuestos)} $ </td>
<td> ${formato.format(item.Total)} $ </td>
```